# how to receive more than 65535 bytes of data on http2 connection from AVS?

Tags: c, ssl, http2, alexa-voice-service, nghttp2

I have implemented an application in C language which communicates with Amazon AVS cloud using nghttp2 and openssl. I can get a response up to 65535 bytes only. If a response is greater than 65535 bytes than application can't receive the rest data and stuck forever to receive the response. As mention earlier, I am using the nghttp2 library for HTTP/2 connection.

Is there any configuration needs to set to get data size more than 65535 bytes from AVS cloud?
Please help.

Comment: Please provide us with some sample code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you can only receive 65535 bytes smells a lot like you are not handling HTTP/2 flow control properly.

I don't know enough of the `nghttp2` library to tell you what you have to do to make sure the flow control is correctly handled, but either you are not using the `nghttp2` API properly (for example, you forgot to notify a callback), or you don't call a `nghttp2` API that handles flow control that you must call.

For reference you can read about flow control [in the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-5.2).

Comment: Exactly. It's important for the client to manage its own flow control window as well. After receiving data, you must at some point emit a WINDOW_UPDATE frame in order to inform the server you can receive more data on your connection, otherwise the initial window (with a default of 65535 bytes) will be consumed!

Comment: Take a look at nghttp2's `nghttp2_submit_window_update` method

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried with "nghttp2_submit_window_update" but still not able to receive data more than 65535 bytes.

Comment: I have used "nghttp2_submit_window_update" function in "on_data_chunk_recv_callback" callback function.
I have observed that sometimes this function call get fail with Flow control Error and sometimes it get succeed but the limit of data size (65535) does not increase.

Comment: Below are the list of callback functions registered for nghttp2:

nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_send_callback(),
nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_recv_callback(), 
nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_frame_send_callback(), 
nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_header_callback(), 
nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_stream_close_callback(), 
nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_on_data_chunk_recv_callback(), 
nghttp2_session_callbacks_set_data_source_read_length_callback().

Comment: You may want to take a look at the `curl` source code to see how it uses `nghttp2` for HTTP/2. `curl` handles flow control properly, so they surely have an example of how to use the `nghttp2` APIs correctly. For example, look [here](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/http2.c).

Comment: I have used the same logic and callbacks for my code as given in curl library but still not able to receive.

Comment: Well, I doubt AWS has deployed a broken server, so it must be something in your client. If you use `curl` instead of your client, does it work ? If you use another HTTP/2 client, does it work ? If the other clients work, then it's something in your client.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, and as a quick workaround, I disabled nghttp2's auto window update via *nghttp2_option_set_no_auto_window_update(option, 1)* API while opening the session and called

*nghttp2_session_consume(session, stream_id, len);
nghttp2_submit_window_update(session, NGHTTP2_FLAG_NONE, stream_id, len);
nghttp2_session_send(session);*

from data chunk recv callback after I am done processing one chunk of data. I am still not sure why keeping auto window update feature of nghttp2 enabled doesn't work.